# Asp.Net IIS hosting

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting

I have an asp.net web application hosted iis on LAN.  When i type in my local ip address in the URL box, i can access it.  My question is, if i want to access it from outside the LAN, would i have to port forward it to port 80? And intead of typing my local ip address in the URL box, i would now have to type the routers ip adress??

Answer (score 1):

Use your internet and LAN address.and put a net forwarding in firewall or port 80 for your internet address.and yes you need to make changes in your firewall as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If your internet address is 7.7.7.7 and your LAN address is 10.10.10.10 -- you'll need to put a NAT/Port-forwarding entry in your router/firewall to send traffic on TCP Port 80 destined for 7.7.7.7 TO 10.10.10.10. On most home routers this is a pretty simple task.

Comment: Probably need to modify your firewall's (you do have a firewall, right?) settings too?